# Dropdown menu: submenu are not displayed correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this following project. [Project Here](https://jsfiddle.net/81wnw0vn/)

Everything works fine but after clicking on the button `Click to expand`, the sub-menu (`Link 1, Link 2, ...`) is displayed at the far left of the button instead of having the same CSS property`left`

Kindly help me know how I can solve this problem. Sorry I am not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this if you add `left: 0` to `.dropdown ul`
[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/81wnw0vn/2/)

If you want to position `ul` relatively to `.dropdown` you can use `position: relative` on `.dropdown` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/81wnw0vn/4/)